# Add a row to TableLayoutPanel only at a specific column

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a table of 1 Row and 2 Columns, I want to add new row at the second columnonly.
I tried to do this not throw the code and didn't succeed.

In which way I can do this?

The row I want to add doesn't get added dynamically

Comment: add a control, the use setcellposition, setcolumn and setrow to position it in the tlp..

Comment: I dont need a code to add tableLayOut..I just want to divide ont column to two rows..thats all

Comment: you can span two rows for the other columns then

Comment: You need to start with two columns and two rows.  Set the RowSpan of the control in the 1st column to 2.

Comment: Are we sure this question is for [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4yc3e8c(v=vs.90).aspx)?  Since this is very easy `tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(myControl, iCol, iRow)` and you can put the control anywhere you want, it even adds rows and columns if they are not there already.